# Jquery: Copy text from a form to a DIV while checking the last letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

On my HTML form, users can enter their name.
Their name will then appear in a DIV as part of a book title.

The book title uses apostrophe 's (e.g. *Amy's Holiday Album*).

If the user enters a name which ends in a S, I don't want the apostrophe s to appear.
(e.g. it should be *Chris' Holiday Album* instead of *Chris's Holiday Album*).

I also only want this to occur if the form has a class of `apostrophe`. If this class does not exist, then the name should be copied as is without any apostrophe or 's'.

I know you can use slice() to get the last character of an element, so I thought I could combine this with an if statement. But it doesn't seem to work.

**[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWH4c/3/)**

Here is my HTML:

```
<div><b class="title"></b> Holiday Album</div>
```

Here is my Jquery (1.8.3):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {


    var finalname = text($(this).val());

    var scheck = finalname.slice(-1);

    var finaltitle;


    if ($(".apostrophe")[0]) {


        if (scheck == 's') {
            finaltitle = finalname + "'";
        }


        else {
            finaltitle = finalname + "'s";
        }


        $('.title').text(finaltitle);
    }

    else {
        $('.title').text(finalname);

    }

});
```

});

Comment: What is `var finalname = text($(this).val());` ?? I think it's a function please put it into fiddle

Comment: It is a new variable which is equal to the value of the users input.

Comment: I know it is variable i'm pointing to `text()`

Comment: text copies over the input (I think). Is that correct?

Comment: removed text method http://jsfiddle.net/rWH4c/4/ . works fine without text method

Comment: No, that isn't there is not such a method name `text()`

Comment: @Surender: That is brilliant, please post as answer, and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text method is not needed on

```
var finalname = $(this).val();
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWH4c/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var finalname = $(this).val();
```

instead of

```
var finalname = text($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Code fires when user starts typing:
    $('.name.apostrophe').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.indexOf("'s") != -1 )  {
            $('.title').text(this.value.replace(/'s/g, "'"));
        } else {
             $('.title').text(this.value)
        }
    }); /* Capture Personalised Message */

});
```

This will also replace all occurrences of the 's with ' only.

Hope it helps!.